# MySQL select query not working.

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$connect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,'a_railway');

if(!$connect)
 {
   die('Could not connect');
  }

$rs="central";
$rd="central";
$s="A";
$d="B";

$dist=call_dist($rs,$rd,$s,$d,$connect);
echo $dist;

function call_dist($rs,$rd,$s,$d,$connect)
{
    $src_dist="SELECT Distance FROM $rs WHERE Station=$s ";
    $dest_dist="SELECT Distance FROM $rs WHERE Station=$d "; 
    $src_dist=mysqli_query($connect,$src_dist);
    $dest_dist=mysqli_query($connect,$dest_dist);
     $dist=abs($src_dist-$dest_dist);
    return $dist;
}
?>
```

why my Sql queries are not working? There is no problem in database. but the queries does not execute. i want to find the distance in this program which is found out by subtracting values at points A and B.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  What happens?  Try to check for `if($src_dist === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error()); }`.  Also remember that [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a resource.  You need to fetch the data using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Have you checked to see what mysqli_query returns? It's giving you a result set, and you can't do maths on a result set in the way you're trying to do.

Comment: yup @andrewsi. getting error 
Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\check\test.php on line 30
how can i convert it to int?

Comment: @SanjayMalhotra - you're getting a resultset back. You need to get a record from the resultset, and then you can do your maths on it.

Comment: i know its dumb question but how can i get record from that?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `station` is a varchar, then you need quotes around the string.

```
$src_dist="SELECT Distance FROM $rs WHERE Station='$s' ";
```

However, you should **not** ever interpolate values in a string like that. Please use prepared statements!

Read this reference, it will make your code and life a lot easier: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**edit** You can also do the math in sql:

```
$dist_query = mysqli_query("SELECT ABS(s.Distance - d.Distance) as dist FROM
                ( SELECT Distance FROM $rs WHERE Station='$s' ) as s,
                ( SELECT Distance FROM $rs WHERE Station='$d' ) as d");
$dist_result = $dist_query->fetch_assoc();
return $dist_result[0]['dist'];
```

Comment: yup i know that is vulnerable to sql injection. i am just a beginner in php so i will definately try yhat next time.

Comment: yup thats an easy approach. but i didn't get what does "as a" and "as d" do?

Comment: It is creating sub-queries and giving the resulting sub-results an alias. In this one sql query, we are first completing two smaller queries, renaming the results, then doing one "outer" query with those results.